# FindBy and OrderBy doesn't order accordingly - Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using this method :

```
List<Client>findTop10ByGenderOrderBySurvey_Results_ScoreDesc(char gender);
```

The logic is this :

I have a Client Model, with a reference OneToMany to the Survey Model, and the Survey Model has a reference of OneToOne with the Results model which has the score field.
So one Client can have many surveys each of which has a score.

I wanted to order the Clients By their score, in descending order, and then get top10 Male Clients with highest score.

The method I'm using does filter By Gender, and returns 10 Clients.
But it returns the same Client more than once,because it has several surveys. And not in an ordered manner.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this ?

```
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "client_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "gender")
private char gender;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference  
private List<Survey> survey= new ArrayList<Survey>();

}



public class Survey{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SURVEY_ID")
private Long Id;

@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
public Client client;


@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
@JoinColumn(name = "surveyresult_id")
private Results surveyResults;

 }

public class Results {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SURVEYRESULT_ID")
private Long Id;

private Double score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter out duplicate results, use the `distinct` keyword:

```
List<Client> findDistinctTop10ByGenderOrderBySurvey_Results_ScoreDesc(char gender);
```

The `OrderBy` syntax is incorrect. To order by multiple properties, simply append them like this:

```
List<Client> findDistinctTop10ByGenderOrderBySurveyDescResultsDescScoreDesc(char gender);
```

Note: When method names become very long, it is a sign the query might be too complex to be a derived query. It is then recommended to use `@Query` with a shorter, higher-level method name to describe the query.